# tr1::mem_fn and tr1::bind: on const-correctness and overloading

Tags: c++, c++11, functional-programming, tr1

What's wrong with the following snippet ?

```
#include <tr1/functional>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std::tr1::placeholders;

struct abc
{
    typedef void result_type;

    void hello(int)
    { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }

    void hello(int) const
    { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }

    abc()
    {}
};

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const abc x;
    int a = 1;

    std::tr1::bind(&abc::hello, x , _1)(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Trying to compile it with g++-4.3, it seems that *cv*-qualifier overloaded functions confuse both `tr1::mem_fn<>` and `tr1::bind<>` and it comes out the following error:

```
no matching function for call to ‘bind(<unresolved overloaded function type>,...
```

Instead the following snippet compiles but seems to break the **const-correctness**:

```
struct abc
{
    typedef void result_type;

    void operator()(int)
    { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }

    void operator()(int) const
    { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }

    abc()
    {}
};

...

    const abc x;
    int a = 1;
    std::tr1::bind( x , _1)(a);
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lookup is done at a time when the constness of `this` is not known.  You just have to give it a hint via casting.  Try this:

```
typedef void (abc::*fptr)(int) const; // or remove const
std::tr1::bind((fptr)&abc::hello, x , _1)(a);
```

You may also notice here that removing the `const` still works.  This is because you should be passing x by pointer (because the first argument to a C++ member function, the implicit `this` parameter, is always a pointer).  Try this instead:

```
typedef void (abc::*fptr)(int) const; // won't compile without const (good!)
std::tr1::bind((fptr)&abc::hello, &x , _1)(a);
```

As discovered during within my comments below, if you omit the `&` as you originally did, you'll be passing x *by value*, which is usually not what you want (though it makes little practical difference in your particular example).  This actually seems like an unfortunate pitfall for `bind`.

Comment: shouldn't bind be expected to evaluate the constness of the object passed as first argument, x in this case ? And what about the second snippet ?

Comment: I don't know.  `bind` is making the call succeed when you pass by value (reference?) and the actual method takes a pointer, but it's not handling constness correctly for some reason.  I don't know why this is.  If someone had a gun to my head and made me guess, I'd mention "The Forwarding Problem."

Comment: Aha!  It's making a copy when you bind and don't pass by pointer.  I will update my answer.

Comment: std::tr1::bind(std::tr1::ref(x) , _1)(a); solves the clue as well :-)

Comment: because of this http://www.open-std.org/Jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#547 , you cannot do tr1::bind(tr1::mem_fn<void(int) const>(&abc::hello), _1); yet -.- let's hope it gets into c++1x

Answer (score 1):

As John suggested, the problems arisen in those snippets are the following:

1. When passing a *member-function-pointer* it's necessary to specify its signature (if overloaded)
2. `bind()` are passed arguments by value.

The first problem is solved by casting the member function pointer provided to bind:

```
    std::tr1::bind(static_cast< void(abc::*)(int) const >(&abc::hello), x, _1)(a);
```

The second can be solved by passing the callable object by address (as John suggested), or by means of TR1 `reference_wrapper<>` -- otherwise it will be passed by value, making the *const-correctness breaking hallucination*.

Given x a callable object:

```
std::tr1::bind( std::tr1::ref(x) , _1)(a);
```

`bind()` will forward `a` to the proper `operator()` in accordance to the x **constness**.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been answered, but I find the best way to specify an overload with bind is to specify it on the template:

```
std::tr1::bind<void(foo::*)(int)>(&foo::bar);
```

This method is just as explicit, but shorter than casting (with `static_cast` anyway. But it's cleaner than the C-cast, which is the same length.